# retrieving all results from LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I need a way to retrive a list of all the users from Ldap. All i need from them is their names to display them in a page.

this is my ldap connection page that retrieve information regarding one user. I need this + the name of all the users.

code:

```
session_start();

include 'includes/connect.php';

// Set the ldap server
$ldapurl = "bpt.kme.intern";
// Set the debug flag
$debug = true;

// Set debugging
if ($debug) {
  ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
}

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapurl) or die ("Couldn't connect"); 


$ldapuser= $_POST['email'];
$ldappass= $_POST['pass'];
$ldaptree    = "OU=BPT_Users,DC=bpt,DC=kme,DC=intern";

echo $ldapuser;
echo $ldappass;


// binding to ldap server
//echo "Trying to bind with $ldapuser - $ldappass\n";
$ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass);

if (!$ldapbind) {
echo "Unable to bind to server $ldapurl\n";
echo "OpenLdap error message: " . ldap_error($ldapconn) . "\n";
$erro = "Dados de Login Inválidos";
$_SESSION['erro']=$erro;
header('location:index.php');


}



if ($ldapbind) {


     $result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(mail=".$ldapuser.")") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));

     //$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
      // SHOW ALL DATA
     //echo '<h1>Dump all data</h1><pre>';
    //print_r($data);   
     //echo '</pre>';

    $entry = ldap_first_entry($ldapconn, $result);
    //Title
    $title = ldap_get_values($ldapconn, $entry, "title");
    //Manager
    $manager = ldap_get_values($ldapconn, $entry, "manager");
    //ACC name
    $samaccountname = ldap_get_values($ldapconn, $entry, "samaccountname");
    //Name
    $nome = ldap_get_values($ldapconn, $entry, "name");


    $_SESSION['logged']=true;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $ldapuser;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $ldappass;
    $_SESSION['title']=$title;
    $_SESSION['manager']=$manager;
    $_SESSION['colab']=$samaccountname;
    $_SESSION['nome']=$nome;


}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the right LDAP filter to use to retrieve all users. This depends on what the entries look like - try to figure out what they have in common. For now, I suppose that all users have a mail attribute and share the objectClass organizationalPerson. In that case, retrieve all the entries like this:

`$result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(&(mail=*)(objectClass=organizationalPerson))") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));`

Then go ahead, either as you tried in your example, or using the `ldap_next_entry` method.

Comment: What kind of loop do i need to echo all the results?

Comment: Beware that depending on the number of users in your LDAP and the configuration of the server there might be limit to the number of returned results which can not be extended from client side. So your might have to do the query in smaller batches.